# On implicit equations of rational quadratic Bézier curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, quadratics, projective-geometry, bezier-curve, homogeneous-equation

Rational quadratic Bézier curve with control points $\boldsymbol{B}_0 = [x_0 : y_0: w_0], \boldsymbol{B}_1 = [x_1 : y_1: w_1], \boldsymbol{B}_2 = [x_2 : y_2: w_2]$
in homogeneous coordinates of $\mathbb{R}P^2$ refer to projective curves of the form
$$
\boldsymbol{B}(t) = [x(t) : y(t) : w(t)],
$$
where
$$
x(t) = x_0(1-t)^2 + 2x_1 (1-t)t + x_2t^2, \\ y(t) = y_0(1-t)^2 + 2y_1 (1-t)t + y_2t^2, \\ w(t) = w_0(1-t)^2 + 2w_1 (1-t)t + w_2t^2.
$$

In [Loop-Blinn 2005](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2005/01/p1000-loop.pdf), section 3.2, it is mentioned that any rational Bézier curve have implicit equation
$$
c(x,y,w) = k^2 - lm,
$$
where $l$, and $m$ are the homogeneous equations of any two lines
tangent to the curve, and $k$ is the line connecting these points of
tangency. With appropriate choice of functionals
$k,l,$ and $m$, any conic section can be represented in this way.

**Problem**: How is the appropriate functionals $k,l,m$ chosen? Why is $c(x,y,w) = k^2 - lm$ a valid implicit equation of the curve?

**Example**: if we consider the unit circle in $\mathbb{R^2}$: $c(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 - 1 = 0$, (recall that unit circle is a rational Bézier curve because it admits a parametrization $\boldsymbol{C}(t) = [1-t^2: 2t: 1+t^2]$) with points of tangency $\boldsymbol{P}_1 = (1,0), \boldsymbol{P}_2 = (0,1),$ then we can set
$$
l(x,y) = x-1, m(x,y) = y-1, k(x,y) = x + y - 1,
$$
so that the line $l=0$ is tangent to the circle at $\boldsymbol{P}_1$, $m=0$ is tangent to the circle at $\boldsymbol{P}_2$, and $k=0$ is the line connecting $\boldsymbol{P}_1$ and $\boldsymbol{P}_2$. Homogenizing $l,m,k$ with appropriate choice, we get
$$
l(x,y,w) = x-w, m(x,y,w) = 2(y-w), k(x,y,w) = x+y-w.
$$
Then
$$
k^2-lm = (x+y-w)^2 - 2(x-w)(y-w)\\ = (x^2 + y^2 + w^2 + 2xy  -2xw -2yw) - (2xy-2wy-2xw+2w^2)\\
= x^2+y^2-w^2,
$$
which is indeed the homogenized equation of the unit circle.

**Observations**: Plugging in $\boldsymbol{P}_1, \boldsymbol{P}_2$ to $k^2 - lm$, one get the output $0$, so $\boldsymbol{P}_1, \boldsymbol{P}_2$ is on the curve $k^2-lm=0$. One can also observe that  $k^2-lm=0$ has tangent lines $l=0$ and $m=0$ at $\boldsymbol{P}_1, \boldsymbol{P}_2$ by calculating the derivative.

Comment: Rational quadratic curves are just conic sections.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Sorry, I might interpret the paper wrong. In the context of this paper, "quadratic curve" refers to "quadratic **Bezier** curve", and "rational quadratic curve" refers to "rational quadratic **Bezier** curve". I will change the description in the question.

Comment: In this way, "quadratic curve" and "rational quadratic curve" are distinct because quadratic Bezier curve can't represent unit circle but rational quadratic Bezier curve can.

Answer (score 1):

Something is fishy here. You can easily have two different conic sections which have the same tangents at two points, but are not the same. Here is an example:

[image]

We have the circle $C = \{x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$, an ellipse $E = \{ x^2 + 4y^2 = 4\}$, and a hyperbola $H = \{ (x+y)(x-y) = 1\}$. They all touch in the two points $P  = (0,1)$ and $Q=(0,-1)$, and have tangents $L = \{y = 1\}$ and $M = \{y = -1\}$ there respectively.

Here is another way to see the same problem: If $l$ and $m$ are linear polynomials which describe the tangent lines at points $P$ and $Q$ respectively, then so are $\alpha l$ and $m$ for any $\alpha \in \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$. However, the polynomials
$$ c = k^2 - lm$$
and
$$\tilde c = k^2 - \alpha lm$$
are implicit equations of very different curves!

In the example above, if you choose $k=x$, $l = 1-y$ and $m = y+1$, you obtain the circle with $\alpha = 1$, the hyperbola with $\alpha = -1$ and the ellipse with $\alpha = 2$. Check this!

My best guess is that the authors mean that for some appropriate choice of $k,l$ and $m$, $k^2 = lm$ describes the curve.

Comment: Thank you, this is a good example. Now that I think about it, "$\boldsymbol{P}_1,\boldsymbol{P}_2$ are on the curve, with tangent lines $l, m$" only gives $4$ equations, but a quadratic curve $ax^2+by^2+cw^2+dxy+eyw+fxw=0$ generally have $5$ parameters $b,c,d,e,f$ (because scale doesn't matter, we can throw away a parameter e.g. $a$). So there is $1$ degree of freedom for the quadratic curve to vary.